# Nearest Neighbour - Error code iterable in Python

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor

Here is the code I'm using and getting an 'int' object is not iterable error and Idon't know how to fix it.

```
def shortestpath(graph,start,end,visited=[],distances={},predecessors={}):
    """Find the shortest path between start and end point of a list"""

    # detect if it's the first time through, set current distance to zero

    if not visited: distances[start]=0

    if start==end:
        # we've found our end point, now find the path to it, and return
        path=[]
        while end != None:
            path.append(end)
            end=predecessors.get(end,None)
        return distances[start], path[::-1]

    # process neighbors as per algorithm, keep track of predecessors
    for neighbor in graph[start]:
        if neighbor not in visited:
            neighbordist = distances.get(neighbor,sys.maxint)
            tentativedist = distances[start] + graph[start][neighbor]
            return tentativedist
            if tentativedist < neighbordist:
                distances[neighbor] = tentativedist
                predecessors[neighbor]=start

    # neighbors processed, now mark the current point as visited
    visited.append(start)

    # finds the closest unvisited node to the start
    unvisiteds = dict((k, distances.get(k,sys.maxint)) for k in graph if k not
    in visited)
    closest = min(unvisiteds, key=unvisiteds.get)

    # now we can take the closest point and recurse, making it current
    return shortestpath(graph,closest,end,visited,distances,predecessors)



#main 
graph=[0,8,7,5,2,10]
n=len(graph)
start=graph[0]
end=graph[n-1]
print shortestpath(graph,start,end)
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the full traceback error, instead of your summary of the message?

Comment: In what way is `[0,8,7,5,2,10]` a graph? How are those integers linked? Where are the edges? How can you determine neighbours from that at all?

Comment: Maybe it's because you didn't spell it neighbour.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `graph=[0,8,7,5,2,10]`, `graph[start]` is an integer therefore you got the error in the for-loop:

```
for neighbor in graph[start]:
```

and I don't think you can use `graph[start][neighbor]` in line: `tentativedist = distances[start] + graph[start][neighbor]`